# How to group elements of a tuple into groups of 6 elements each?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, function-construction

I have a large tuple and I want to elements of the tuples into groups of 6 elements like this:

```
{{a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8}, {a3, a2, a1, a6, a5, a4, a8, 
  a7}, {-a1 - a3, a2, a1, -a4 - a6, a5, a4, -a7 - a8, a7}, {a1, 
  a2, -a1 - a3, a4, a5, -a4 - a6, a7, -a7 - a8}, {-a1 - a3, a2, 
  a3, -a4 - a6, a5, a6, -a7 - a8, a8}, {a3, a2, -a1 - a3, a6, 
  a5, -a4 - a6, a8, -a7 - a8}}.
```

This is the input and output samples but with a small number of elements.

```
inputTup = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 8, 7}, {-4, 
    2, 1, -10, 5, 4, -15, 7}, {1, 2, -4, 4, 5, -10, 7, -15}, {-4, 2, 
    3, -10, 5, 6, -15, 8}, {3, 2, -4, 6, 5, -10, 8, -15}, {1, 2, 3, 4,
     5, 6, 8, 8} , {1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}};
outputSample = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 8, 
    7}, {-4, 2, 1, -10, 5, 4, -15, 7}, {1, 2, -4, 4, 5, -10, 
    7, -15}, {-4, 2, 3, -10, 5, 6, -15, 8}, {3, 2, -4, 6, 5, -10, 
    8, -15}};
```

How can I do it?
I thought about Gather function but still not able to implement it with this large selection conditions like this.

**EDIT**:

As it seems like my question not clear enough, I will give another example of simpler problem but of same form.

Assume that I have a list of list like this. The list here has 8 sublists but in reality there are much more.

```
input = {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 0, 1}, {-2, 1, 3}, {1, -2, 3}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 
  1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 5}}
```

Now I want to group tuples of the form below into groups:

```
{{a1, a2, a3}, {-a2, a1, a3}, {a1, -a2, a3}}
```

where a1, a2, a3 can be any number.

And this is the desired output. Notice that there are two groups satisfying the condition above.

```
output ={{{1, 2, 3}, {-2, 1, 3}, {1, -2, 3}}, {{1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 
   1}}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 5}}
```

Two groups satisfying the condition above:

```
group1 = {{1, 2, 3}, {-2, 1, 3}, {1, -2, 3}}
group2 = {{1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}}
```

Comment: I am not sure I  follow. In your inputTup you have eight lists and in your outputSample you have six lists. The first six lists in inputTup are equivalent to the six lists in outputSample. You are wondering how to go from inputTup to outputSample? Or you are wondering how to take a generic list of eight elements (a1->a8) and then create a list of lists, where the a1->a8 elements are ordered as specified in each sublist?

Comment: @a20 you could take the other two elements into the outputSample. I removed it to make it clear that I want to group the input into groups of groups where each group is of the form given in the first code box. The length of input list is large which could be 10000 elements.

Comment: Are the elements of the lists always integers, or at least always numeric?

Comment: @march yes, integers only

Comment: In addition, is there some obvious symmetry operation whose orbit is the entire set of forms?  For example, is there an operation that turns `{a1, a2, a3}` into `{-a2, a1, a3}` into `{a1, -a2, a3}` into `{a1, a2, a3}`? (I don't think it even needs to be invertible, but that would help.) That way, you can use the operation to define an equivalence relation, and then you'd be able to use `Gather` or `GatherBy` with a functionalized version of the operation.

Comment: @march every sublist includes all parameters a1, a2, a3 but I don't understand what symmetry  you're saying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ClearAll[alikeQ, gatherAlike]
alikeQ[lst_] := Module[{pat = Pattern[#,_] & /@ First[lst], patterns}, 
    patterns[Evaluate @ pat] := lst; 
    MemberQ[patterns @ #, #2]] &;

gatherAlike = Gather[#, alikeQ @ #2] &;
```

***Examples:***

*OP's first example:*

```
eighttuples = {{a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8}, {a3, a2, a1, a6, a5, a4, a8, a7}, 
    {-a1 - a3, a2, a1, -a4 - a6, a5, a4, -a7 - a8, a7},
    {a1, a2, -a1 - a3, a4, a5, -a4 - a6, a7, -a7 - a8},
    {-a1 - a3, a2, a3, -a4 - a6, a5, a6, -a7 - a8, a8}, 
    {a3, a2, -a1 - a3, a6, a5, -a4 - a6, a8, -a7 - a8}};

inputTup = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 8, 7}, 
    {-4, 2, 1, -10, 5, 4, -15, 7}, {1, 2, -4, 4, 5, -10, 7, -15}, 
    {-4, 2, 3, -10, 5, 6, -15, 8}, {3, 2, -4, 6, 5, -10, 8, -15}, 
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 8}, {1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}};

gatherAlike[inputTup, eighttuples] // Column
```

[image]

Select groups with more than one member:

```
Select[Length @ # > 1 &] @ gatherAlike[inputTup, eighttuples] // Column
```

[image]

*OP's second example:*

```
triples = {{a1, a2, a3}, {-a2, a1, a3}, {a1, -a2, a3}};

input = {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 0, 1}, {-2, 1, 3}, {1, -2, 3}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1},
   {1, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 5}};

gatherAlike[input, triples] // Column
```

[image]

```
Select[Length @ # > 1 &] @ gatherAlike[input, triples] // Column
```

[image]

*A random example:*

```
thesearealike = {{a1, a2, a3, a4}, {a4, a3, a2, a1}, {a4 + a1, a3, a2, a1 + a4}};

SeedRandom[1]
randominput = DeleteDuplicates@RandomInteger[{1, 4}, {100, 4}];

Length @ randominput
```

> ```
> 81
> ```

```
Select[Length @ # > 1 &] @ gatherAlike[randominput, thesearealike] // Column
```

[image]

Comment: If you modify the triple like this `triples = {{-a1, a2, a3}, {-a2, a1, a3}, {a1, -a2, a3}};` then `gatherAlike[input, triples]` you would get an error saying `First element in pattern Pattern[-a1,_] is not a valid pattern name.` How would you solve this?

Comment: Or triples = {{-a1+a2, a2, a3}, {-a2, a1, a3}, {a1, -a2, a3}} also doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

You can first define a 3D matrix (dimensions 6 x 8 x 8) with the appropiate coefficients:

```
matTotal = {{{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}, {{0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 
 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}}, {{-1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
  0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
 0}}, {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {-1, 
 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1}}, {{-1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0,
  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -1, 0,
  -1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}, {{0, 
 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, -1, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
 0}, {0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 
 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1}}};
```

And then use standard matrix product with your input vector:

```
matTotal . {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
```

to get the output vectors:

```
{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 8, 7}, {-4, 2, 1, -10, 
  5, 4, -15, 7}, {1, 2, -4, 4, 5, -10, 7, -15}, {-4, 2, 3, -10, 5, 
  6, -15, 8}, {3, 2, -4, 6, 5, -10, 8, -15}}
```

Answer (score 2):

My approach is to define a function `equivalenceClass` that takes a given tuple and maps it to its full equivalence class and then use `GatherBy[input,equivalenceClass]`. The problem is to construct this function. Also, since `equivalenceClass` will be called many times, we have to hope that `equivalenceClass` can be made fast (which also includes that the output is not overly large).

I the following I assume that given a tuple `{a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,8}` its the full equivalence class is already given by `eighttuples`. *I have not checked that this assumption is true.*
To standardize this (making it possible for *Mathematica* to compare equivalence class of different tuples), we generate all tuples and sort afterwards:

```
eighttuples = {
   {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8},
   {a3, a2, a1, a6, a5, a4, a8, a7},
   {-a1 - a3, a2, a1, -a4 - a6, a5, a4, -a7 - a8, a7},
   {a1, a2, -a1 - a3, a4, a5, -a4 - a6, a7, -a7 - a8},
   {-a1 - a3, a2, a3, -a4 - a6, a5, a6, -a7 - a8, a8},
   {a3, a2, -a1 - a3, a6, a5, -a4 - a6, a8, -a7 - a8}
   };

equivalenceClass = Block[{a},
   Function @@ {a, eighttuples /. {
       a1 -> Indexed[a, 1], a2 -> Indexed[a, 2], a3 -> Indexed[a, 3], 
       a4 -> Indexed[a, 4],
       a5 -> Indexed[a, 5], a6 -> Indexed[a, 6], a7 -> Indexed[a, 7], 
       a8 -> Indexed[a, 8]
       }}
   ];
```

Now `GatherBy` should return the correct result. But it is kind of slow:

```
input = RandomInteger[{-6, 6}, {1000000, 8}];
groupsslow = GroupBy[input, equivalenceClass]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 25.9858

The bottleneck is that the evaluation of `equivalenceClass` is too slow at the moment. So we use `Compile` to speed it up.

```
cEquivalenceClass = Block[{a},
   With[{
     class = eighttuples /. {
        a1 -> Compile`GetElement[a, 1],
        a2 -> Compile`GetElement[a, 2],
        a3 -> Compile`GetElement[a, 3],
        a4 -> Compile`GetElement[a, 4],
        a5 -> Compile`GetElement[a, 5],
        a6 -> Compile`GetElement[a, 6],
        a7 -> Compile`GetElement[a, 7],
        a8 -> Compile`GetElement[a, 8]
        }
     },
    
    Compile[{{a, _Integer, 1}},
     Sort[class],
     CompilationTarget -> "C",
     RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
     ]
    ]
   ];
```

Here `Compile`GetElement`is a fancy replacement for`Index`that in conjunction with`RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"` suppresses some bound checks in the compiled library, making it slightly faster.

Now we get

```
groups = GatherBy[input, cEquivalenceClass]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 1.30694

Maybe that makes it already practical for you.

In principle, this can be improved. I don't know what kind of sorting algorithm *Mathematica* uses for the short list like we have here. Since the length of the list is known and compile time, a sorting network could speed up the `Sort` quite a lot. Also the problem allows a divide-and-conquer approach to parallelize this: Each processor get just a share of tuples and groups them. That will be the bulk of work. Merging the groups generated by the processors should be fast as long as there are substantially fewer groups than there are elements in `input`.

It is also possible to run a prefiltering step with a very coarse classifier (or hash) function that cannot differentiate between all equivalence classes but that is cheap to evaluate. In this example, this could be

```
coarsegroups = GatherBy[input, Sort[Abs[#]] &];
```

Then it is guaranteed that all elements of a given equivalence class are contained in a single sublist of `coarsegroups`. The finer classification can then be run on each of these sublists in parallel. Whether this is faster probably depends on how long the outputs of `cEquivalenceClass` are and on the precise algorithm that *Mathematica* uses for `GatherBy`. If it uses direct comparisons of outputs of `cEquivalenceClass`, then this prefilterung might help. But if uses some hashing technique with a really good hashing function for integer matices (which I expect), then this prefiltering probably won't help much. (It did not in the current example.)

Comment: Thank you for the nice solution. I'll read it in detail and accept in a few days.

Comment: Thank you! I am glad that I could help.