# How to generate non-duplicate list of tuples with integer elements {-2, 0, 2}?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, function-construction

How can I generate all possible non-duplicate `eighttupleList` where each element, $a_i$, can be an integer from the set {-2, 0, 2}?

```
eighttupleList = {{a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8}, {a3, a2, a1, a6, a5, 
    a4, a8, a7}, {-a1 - a3, a2, a1, -a4 - a6, a5, a4, -a7 - a8, 
    a7}, {a1, a2, -a1 - a3, a4, a5, -a4 - a6, 
    a7, -a7 - a8}, {-a1 - a3, a2, a3, -a4 - a6, a5, a6, -a7 - a8, 
    a8}, {a3, a2, -a1 - a3, a6, a5, -a4 - a6, a8, -a7 - a8}};
```

The motivation is similar to my [previous](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/259472/how-to-group-elements-of-a-tuple-into-groups-of-6-elements-each) thread; I want to group all elements in a list with a pattern.

```
inputTup = Tuples[{-2, 0, 2}, 8];
eighttupleList = {{a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8}, {a3, a2, a1, a6, 
    a5, a4, a8, a7}, {-a1 - a3, a2, a1, -a4 - a6, a5, a4, -a7 - a8, 
    a7}, {a1, a2, -a1 - a3, a4, a5, -a4 - a6, 
    a7, -a7 - a8}, {-a1 - a3, a2, a3, -a4 - a6, a5, a6, -a7 - a8, 
    a8}, {a3, a2, -a1 - a3, a6, a5, -a4 - a6, a8, -a7 - a8}};
```

If I can generate all `eighttupleList`, then I basically already gathered `inputTup` into the `eighttupleList` pattern.

I can do something like that, but some of them are duplicates.

```
rule = Thread[{a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8} -> #] & /@ Tuples[{-2, 0, 2}, {8}]; 
eighttupleList /. rule
```

Comment: When you say "non-duplicate list of tuples", do you mean list of tuples such that that list does not contain the same tuple twice?

Comment: Does `eightTupleList[{a1_, a2_, a3_, a4_, a5_, a6_, a7_, a8_}] := {{a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8}, {a3, a2, a1, a6, a5, a4, a8, a7}, {-a1 - a3, a2, a1, -a4 - a6, a5, a4, -a7 - a8, a7}, {a1, a2, -a1 - a3, a4, a5, -a4 - a6, a7, -a7 - a8}, {-a1 - a3, a2, a3, -a4 - a6, a5, a6, -a7 - a8, a8}, {a3, a2, -a1 - a3, a6, a5, -a4 - a6, a8, -a7 - a8}}`; `Select[eightTupleList /@ Tuples[{-2,0,2}, 8], DuplicateFreeQ]` do what you expect?

Comment: I meant two eight-tuple lists do not duplicate. For example, I can do something like that, but some of them are duplicates. ```rule = Thread[{a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8} -> #] & /@ 
   Tuples[{-2, 0, 2}, {8}];
eighttupleList /. rule```

Comment: @thorimur Sorry for the confusion. I have just updated the post to provide more details.

Comment: This is still hard to follow. Do you mean like this? `Map[DeleteDuplicates, eighttupleList /. rule]`? This deletes duplicates in each sublist.

Comment: Hmm, it's still not clear what you mean by phrases like "all `eightTupleList`", "gathered", and "pattern" (note that in Mathematica a pattern is a specific kind of thing, like `a1_`, but not `a1`. Technically, `a1` can be used as a pattern, but it only matches the literal symbol `a1`.) But I trust there is something that you mean! :) Let's formalize things a little to make them clearer. [ctd.]

Comment: Define $M : \{-2,0,2\}^8 \to (\{-2,0,2\}^8)^6$ as the map $(a_1, \cdots, a_8) \mapsto ((a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5, a_6, a_7, a_8), (a_3, a_2, a_1, a_6, a_5, a_4, a_8, a_7), (-a_1 - a_3, a_2, a_1, -a_4 - a_6, a_5, a_4, -a_7 - a_8, a_7), (a_1, a_2, -a_1 - a_3, a_4, a_5, -a_4 - a_6, a_7, -a_7 - a_8), (-a_1 - a_3, a_2, a_3, -a_4 - a_6, a_5, a_6, -a_7 - a_8, a_8), (a_3, a_2, -a_1 - a_3, a_6, a_5, -a_4 - a_6, a_8, -a_7 - a_8))$. Are you looking for the image of $M$ (regarded as a set—no duplicates)? Or are you looking to delete duplicates from *each* tuple-of-tuples returned by $M$? Or something else?

Comment: One thing I suspect is that you are using an unstated notion of what it means for two things to be "the same" and thus be "duplicates". If you can make this precise, it'll be easier to help. :)